# response.headers['content-type'] is inconsistent on image url

Tags: node.js, request, mime-types, content-type

I have a very simple url verification function in node. This function takes an image url and makes a request to that url using the `request` module. I then check content-type on the response. However, intermittently I get the error : `File Type 'text/html; charset=utf-8' is not supported`, which is an error that is expected if someone tries to retrieve an image type I do not support. As it is intermittent, I am having some trouble figuring out what I have done wrong.

```
let request = require('request');

function verifyImage(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const imgTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'];
      request(url, (error, response) => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        }
        if (!imgTypes.includes(response.headers['content-type'])) {
          reject(`File Type ${response.headers['content-type']} is not supported`)
        }
        resolve(response.statusCode);
      })
    })
}
```

The example url I am using is `https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQDoWX9zu4XvJYRF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.manutd.com%2F%7E%2Fmedia%2F3390670C247245C29BF10C98C6D454C1.ashx&_nc_hash=AQA-e6n3PXxemXam`

Comment: What's the issue you are facing, i ran your code with the url specified everything is working fine.

Comment: @kgangadhar That just means you have not hit the intermittent issue here. As mentioned, the intermittent problem is that, for the same url, I intermittently get an error on content-type

Comment: If there is nothing glaringly obvious thats wrong, it could be another issue, and I'll go ahead and close this question.

Comment: I checked regarding this, there is one open issue for [request](https://github.com/request/request/issues/2336) in github, but don't know what is the exact reason behind this .

Comment: @kgangadhar Thanks for posting that. If I see this again, I may revert back to the native https implementation.